# Creating from scratch a ListView with on_selection_change() event

Tags: python, listview, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to use Kivy and Python to make a screen that changes basing in what is selected in the ListView which is created using the information of mydb, but I can't find any instructions on how to made from scratch and the documentation is not very clear on how I use things like binding and the on_selection_change() method, I'm completely lost. This is my code until now:

```
class PrincipalView(ListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PrincipalView, self).__init__()
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","mydb")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        objList = ObjList(cursor)
        data = [{'text': item.name, 'is_selected': False} for item in objList.list]
        args_converter = lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text'],
                                     'size_hint_y': None,
                                     'height': 25}
        list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=data,
                       args_converter=args_converter,
                       cls=ListItemButton,
                       selection_mode='single',
                       allow_empty_selection=False)
        self.adapter=list_adapter
```

My goal is to change a grid layout which is next to the listview in the screen using some of the data in objList.

Comment: Try adding `self.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)` at the end of your `__init__` method, and add a `callback` method to your `PrincipalView` class.

Comment: You shouldn't use ListView, it's been deprecated and will be dropped in futur versions, RecycleView is the way to go.